# I cannot create a react app with npx create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-install

Whenever I try to create a react app with npx create-react-app I get a folder with a single file in it along with the message "Missing dependencies in package.json."
The contents of package.json, the one file in the folder, s:
{
"name": "plzwurk",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true
}

npm version:8.19.2
node version: v18.12.1

How can I fix this?

I have fully uninstalled npm and node. I tried different versions, restarting my system, and everything else I could find.

Comment: Try to install yarn and then run "npx create-react-app my-app"

Comment: Your package.json is nothing but a regular npm init boilerplate code. run the above command. Or follow https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app